# Black column of pixels when rendering in HDRI pranorama

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, hdri

Was rendering some HDRIs to use in other scenes as lighting when I noticed the very last column of pixels on the image to the left was not rendering and came out as black. Since this is a 32-bit image it's a bit of a pain to fix in PS, does anyone know a fix? Also, it should be mentioned I am using Blender 2.8. [image: Last column is black]

Answer (score 1):

Literally seconds after I posted this I figured it out, lol. Turns out this is what happens when the Lens Distortion is used for some reason.